# Only one of two media functions work in CSS

Tags: css

Only the second `@media` tag is applied to my css, and when using chrome dev tools the it only shows the second one in the css tag.

```
@media screen
  and (max-device-width: 600px)
  and (min-device-width: 0px)
  {
  #navLink {
    font-size: 1.6em;
  }
}
@media screen
  and (max-device-width: 2000px)
  and (min-device-width: 600px)
  {
  #navLink {
    font-size: 35px;
  }
}
```

Comment: It's correct behavior for the browser, it will show only applied media queries. And it's not possible that both of your queries will be applied at the same time

Comment: Off topic but won't both rules is true if the device's width is `600px`?